# Getting "Error: An unexpected error has occurred." while deploying firebase function

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a firebase function  for my Android application. I referred the Google's official documentation for the deployment of the function. Below is the link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-landmarks#deploy-the-callable-function

Right after I use the deploy command I get the below error:

```
> firebase deploy --only functions:annotateImage

=== Deploying to 'capstone-1e935'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "%$RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\USER\Downloads\functions-samples\vision-annotate-images\%C:\Users\USER\Downloads\functions-samples\vision-annotate-images\functions%'
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!!!